# Unable to uninstall python-wxgtk3.0 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, uninstall

When I try to uninstall this package, I get the message that

> python-wxgtk3.0
> installed python-wxgtk3.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Here is the output:

```
After this operation, 30.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 308794 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-wxgtk3.0 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing package python-wxgtk3.0 (--remove):
 installed python-wxgtk3.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/wx/python/wx3.0.pth doesn't exist
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-wxgtk3.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-wxgtk3.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Maybe you removed another python package before python-wxgtk3.0 ? I.e. removing essential python could be the cause of your unusual error ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yes, I think I did it. Then I reinstalled Python from source code. However, I don't know how to fix this problem now.

Comment: Never touch the system python. All package handling, in out, depends on it. ......... Fix : If you know exactly what you did, repair the OS from an external live OS. Else, make backups , and reinstall.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I'm surprised Python (and, in particular, Python 2) is so integrated into the Ubuntu system.